# What will customer need to do to run WPF app build on .NET Core 3.0?

Tags: wpf, .net-core

.NET Core 3.0 was released yesterday and I wonder what will customer need to run WPF app built on .NET core 3.0

1. Say customer is using Windows 10. Will customer need to install first Runtime for .NET Core 3.0?
2. Say customer is using Windows 7. What does customer need to do to run application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You as a developer will have to convert and recompile your current WPF against .NET Core 3 and then redeploy it. [This](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2018/12/15/wpf-on-net-core/) blog post should provide a good starting point.

> Say customer is using Windows 10. Will customer need to install first Runtime for .NET Core 3.0?

.NET Core supports [three types of deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/). For self-contained deployments (SCD), the end user doesn't have to install anything but [the native dependencies of .NET Core for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x).

> Say customer is using Windows 7. What does customer need to do to run application?

Same thing as for Windows 10 basically. .NET Core 3 requires Windows 7 SP 1 or later: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.0/3.0-supported-os.md#windows

Also note that .NET Core 3 supports [single-file executables](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2019/09/22/single-file-exes-in-net-core/) that bundle together all framework specific and referenced DLLs, configuration files and other content in a single native .exe that you can distribute to your end users.